# Не получается вывести данные о товаре VirtueMart

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

В дублированном файле модуля `mod_virtuemart_category` такой код:

```
$productModel = VmModel::getModel('Product');
$products = $productModel->getProductListing(false, false, true, true, true, true, $category->virtuemart_category_id, false, 0);
............
<?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
    <?php
        if (!empty($product->images[0])) {
                            $image = $product->images[0]->displayMediaThumb ('class="featuredProductImage"', FALSE);
        } else {
            $image = '';
        }
        echo JHTML::_ ('link', JRoute::_ ('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=' . $product->virtuemart_product_id . '&virtuemart_category_id=' . $product->virtuemart_category_id), $image, array('title' => $product->product_name));
    ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Но изображение товара не выводится. То же самое и с ценой:

```
<?php if ($show_price) {
    if (!empty($product->prices['salesPrice'])) {
        echo $currency->createPriceDiv ('salesPrice', '', $product->prices, FALSE, FALSE, 1.0, TRUE);
    }
    if (!empty($product->prices['salesPriceWithDiscount'])) {
        echo $currency->createPriceDiv ('salesPriceWithDiscount', '', $product->prices, FALSE, FALSE, 1.0, TRUE);
    }
}
?>
```

Хотя код `<?php echo $product->product_name ?>` название товара выводит. Цены и изображение для товара заданы. В переопределенном модуле `mod_virtuemart_product` этот код работает нормально.